# Hyperledger v1.0 - Java SDK register chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I found how to [run Hyperledger locally with Docker](https://blog.craftworkz.co/run-hyperledger-locally-with-docker-4f3bcb815c03#.wcycbc5ih).
But I didn't find any tutorial how to register chaincode using Java SDK.
Can someone share how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Fabric version 1.0 is still under development and the release is not final at this point.  This is not a tutorial, but information about the Java SDK for Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 is available [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java).  Note that this mentions that version 1.0 is currently a preview and APIs are subject to change.  As far as an example on deploying chaincode with the Java SDK, this [site](https://github.com/GrapeBaBa/hyperledger-java) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best starting place currently is this:

[Java SDK End-to-end Test Scenario](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java#end-to-end-test-scenario)

Which takes you through the process of creating a channel, and deploying some chaincode on it, and running some basic operations with that chaincode.

To run this, you will have to:

- Get the latest Docker Fabric images (using something like the script detailed in section 3.1 of the [Hyperledger Fabric documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hyperledger-fabric/master/hyperledger-fabric.pdf), which uses this script [bootstrap-1.0.1.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.1.sh)),
- Launch the network using the script you can find in the directory "src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/fabric.sh"
- Run the test case as detailed in [running-the-integration-tests](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java#running-the-integration-tests)

Once you have it running, you can pick the code apart and see what it is doing.